# Scala 'fromFile' weirdness?

Tags: scala, io

I can't understand why two bits of code that are meant to do exactly the same thing, do different things in Scala.

*First example:*

```
scala> val ggg = Source.fromFile("/somefile");
ggg: scala.io.BufferedSource = non-empty iterator

scala> ggg.getLines();
res67: Iterator[String] = empty iterator
```

*Second example:*

```
scala> Source.fromFile("/somefile").getLines();
res68: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator
```

**Aren't they meant to do the same thing, or am I missing something?**

Comment: You don't need the semicolons. It works for me in REPL (2.8.2.RC1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a quirk (bug?) with `BufferedSource.toString`. Observe:

```
// no problem
scala> { val x = Source.fromFile("foo.txt"); x.getLines() }
res10: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

// ahh, calling toString somehow emptied our iterator
scala> { val x = Source.fromFile("foo.txt"); println(x.toString); x.getLines() }
non-empty iterator
res11: Iterator[String] = empty iterator
```

To show the value of the expression, the REPL needs to call `BufferedSource.toString`, and this has the side effect of emptying the iterator.

Comment: I can't repro this or the original report on 2.8.0.final on FreeBSD.  I tried with big files, one line files, and empty files.

Comment: I'm using 2.9.1RC1 on OS X. Sounds like a regression. I just noticed I can't reproduce this on a nightly build, so it seems to be fixed in trunk.

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4662 / Fix: https://codereview.scala-lang.org/fisheye/changelog/scala-svn?cs=25212

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this bug: [SI-4662](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4662).

Apparently fixed in trunk [Changeset 25212](https://codereview.scala-lang.org/fisheye/changelog/scala-svn?cs=25212), but not in 2.9.1 as far as I can see.

In the bug notes it's mentioned that it probably manifests itself only in the REPL, not in "real" code.